# Cannot get background colour to appear for div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a background colour for this div, but for some reason its remaining transparent (not displaying). What have I missed?

```
    <div class="chesse_people">
        <img class="badge-icon" src="img/cheese_expert.jpg">
        <h4>Chief Cheese Taster - Dave Le Conk</h4>
        <p class="chesse_people">text here.</p>
    </div>


     .cheese_people {
     background-color: #ed6c85; 
     float:left;
     width:70%;
     }

    .badge-icon {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    }
```

Comment: You misspelled your class. `class="chesse_people"` should be `class="cheese_people"`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2JvCe/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your class (`cheese_people`) does not match your element class (`<div class="chesse_people">`).

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, you spelled it wrong. At first I thought underscores were invalid in CSS, but I looked it up and they're not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misspelling in your code: see fixed code below:

```
    <div class="cheese_people">
        <img class="badge-icon" src="img/cheese_expert.jpg">
        <h4>Chief Cheese Taster - Dave Le Conk</h4>
        <p class="cheese_people">text here.</p>
    </div>


     .cheese_people {
          background-color: #ed6c85; 
          float:left;
          width:70%;
     }

    .badge-icon {
        float:left;
        margin-right:20px;
    }
```